# How to use node-simple-schema reactively?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs, simple-schema, meteor-tracker

Given that there is not much examples about this, I am following the [docs](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#enable-meteor-tracker-reactivity) as best as I can, but the validation is not reactive.

I declare a schema :

```
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export const modelSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  foo: { 
    type: String,
    custom() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addValidationErrors([{ name: 'foo', type: 'notUnique' }]);
      }, 100);  // simulate async
      return false;
    }
  }
}, {
  tracker: Tracker
});
```

then I use this schema in my component :

```
export default class InventoryItemForm extends TrackerReact(Component) {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.validation = modelSchema.newContext();
    this.state = {
      isValid: this.validation.isValid()
    };
  }

  ...

  render() {
    ...
    const errors = this.validation._validationErrors;

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

So, whenever I try to validate `foo`, the asynchronous' custom function is called, and the proper `addValidationErrors` function is called, but the component is never re-rendered when `this.validation.isValid()` is supposed to be false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two errors in your code. Firstly `this.addValidationErrors` cannot be used asynchronously inside custom validation, as it does not refer to the correct validation context. Secondly, `TrackerReact` only registers reactive data sources (such as `.isValid`) inside the `render` function, so it's not sufficient to only access `_validationErrors` in it. Thus to get it working you need to use a named validation context, and call `isValid` in the render function (or some other function called by it) like this:

**in the validation**

```js
custom() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    modelSchema.namedContext().addValidationErrors([
      { name: 'foo', type: 'notUnique' }
    ]);
  }, 100);
}
```

**the component**

```js
export default class InventoryItemForm extends TrackerReact(Component) {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.validation = modelSchema.namedContext();
  }

  render() {
    let errors = [];
    if (!this.validation.isValid()) {
      errors = this.validation._validationErrors;
    }

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

See more about asynchronous validation [here](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#asynchronous-custom-validation-on-the-client).

Comment: I find that weird (and an anti-pattern) to use a named context inside the schema itself... so to have this validation, it *needs* to always use this same schema? What if I'd have a template where the user can add in batch multiple models; would I use the same context for all of them? What if one fails, the others would display the error as well? I used `this.addValidationErrors` as I supposed that the validation function would receive the context at call time! Are you saying that it is not the case?

Comment: @YanickRochon TBH I don't really understand the pattern either. I see you opened issues with the package, I was about to suggest that.

Comment: exactly. This is why I suggested the PR. I can get way with it if I specify the context to the `extendedCustomContext`, but I believe that the `getContext()` proposal is a far better normalized way. Anyway, thank you for your explanations, I re-read `TrackerReact` source code and understand better how it works :) Cheers!